# wstring to size_t

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, casting, wstring

I would like to cast a wstring to size_t.

I have tried this:

```
wstring SomeWString=L"100";
size_t SomeValue;
SomeValue=_wtoi(SomeWString);
```

But that is not a valid conversion. VS2012 tells me:

> There is no compatible conversion function for casting std::wstring to
>   const_wchar_t*.

Can somebody please tell me how this should be done? Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939260/convert-string-to-int-with-stringstream

Comment: I don't want to use such a big conversion. I was hoping there would be something like _wtost(), but I did not find a fitting function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_wtoi` expects an argument of type `const wchar_t*`, but you're providing a `wstring`.

Try the following:

```
SomeValue = _wtoi(SomeWString.c_str());
```